# display columns in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, col

I want to display 4 columns in AngularJS:

This is my html so far:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">Desc1:</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6"> Desc2:</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {{value1}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {{value2}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
            Desc1:
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
            Desc2:
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
            Desc3:
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-6">          
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{value1}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{value2}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{value3}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to display is something like this:

```
Desc1     value1     Desc1    value1 
Desc2     value2     Desc2    value2
                     Desc3    value3
```

For example if one value returns nothing I want that row to be empty. With my current code, if one value returns nothing then the next value gets shifted over and displayed.  This messes up everything past that point.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly you want to show the div even if it has no value? Try `{{value1 || '&nbsp;'}}`

Comment: yes, that is what I want to do

Comment: use table instead of div.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS (which is a better way to go)

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```